# Use Green's Theorem to compute the area inside the curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

So every time I use Green's theorem to calculate the area... I get $0$; here is the curve:
$x = 2\cos(t)$ , $y =\sin(2t)$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

The equation I am using is $$A = \frac{1}{2} \int_C xdy - ydx.$$

Perhaps I am using the wrong equation? I basically plug in $x, y , dy$, and $dx$ and then integrate with respect to $t$ from the given parameter. Is this wrong?

Comment: I'm curious what you get for $dy$ and $dx$.

Comment: dy = 2cos(2t) and dx = -2sin(t)

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is.  Have you plotted this curve out?  You might be able to see the issue yourself. Hint: areas calculated this way are signed based on the orientation of the curve.

Comment: yes... I have plotted it out... it looks like a sideways hour glass with the curve intersecting 0. should i go from -Pi to Pi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Curve $C$ is symmetrical, therefore 
$$A=4\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)\right)\ dt}.$$

Answer (score 4):

No, changing the bounds will not help you here. The area is signed (or "oriented").  An easy way to look at this is to form the cross product $dA = r \times v \, dt$, where $v = dr/dt$.  You should be able to see that, for $x > 0$, this cross product is in the positive $z$-direction.  For $x < 0$, this cross product is in the negative $z$-direction.  The two halves have opposite orientations.

By symmetry, both halves have the same area, but since they're oriented in opposite directions, they cancel out, and you end up with zero.

Comment: so should i do 0 to Pi then double it if i dont want signed area.. Im a bit confused because i see an example of a circle and they do not get 0.

Comment: A circle doesn't self-intersect the way this particular curve does. Each sector has the same orientation as any other sector, so there's no cancellation.  If you do $(0, \pi)$, you will still get zero--you'll get one quarter on the left and one quarter on the right that still cancel.